# ant : Parameter -command is specified already

Tags: mobile, touch

I am working on Salesforce Touch; I am new with this platform. I am referring to the Salesforce Touch guide. I am trying to create a native Android project, using this command

```
ant create_native -Dapp.name={DemoApp} -Dtarget.dir={C:\Anu Raj\project\Salesforce Touch} -Dpackage.name={com.acme.mobileapp}"
```

but i am getting this error while doing this --- > "

```
ant : Parameter -command is specified already.
At line:1 char:4
+ ant <<<<  create_native -Dapp.name={DemoApp} -Dtarget.dir={C:\} -Dpackage.nam
e={com.acme.mobileapp}
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParameterBindingExcepti
on
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterSpecifiedAlready
```

can anybody tell me what is the issue for this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You have a space in the directory name "Anu Raj"

You should either use a directory name which does not have spaces or use double quotes to make sure that the path is resolved correctly in case it contains spaces.

Hope this helps.